# Return specific functions of a class from another function

Tags: python, oop

I have 2 classes, A and B

```py
class A:

    def name(self):
        return B(name=self)

class B:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def hi(self):
        return "Hi!" + self.name

    def bye(self):
        return "Bye!" + self.name


print(A.name('Robert').hi())
print(A.name('Robert').bye()) # I don't want this :(
```

This prints out `Hi! Robert` and `Bye! Robert`, however, class A has access to bye() (which I do not want). Is there a way to limit the functions of B which A.name can access?

Comment: Correct OOP use is `A('Robert').name()` and give A a `__init__`

Comment: You claim that "class A has access to bye()". It does not. Rather, for reasons I don't understand, you have implemented the A.name() method to return a B instance, and that B instance (of course) has access to the methods of its own class. Why is A.name() returning a new B instance? That's the key question. Perhaps if you explain why you implemented it that way, you'll get more useful help in response.

Comment: I am sorry that I did not explain my question correctly, A actually has many more functions and so does B. Each of A's functions use different functions of B. Hence I cannot use init because I want to pass a value to the individual functions. A.name() is returning a B instance since I need a way for the end-user/programmer to use multiple functions of B while passing the value through  a function of A. So my question was, can a function of A return only certain functions of B instead of all.

Answer (score 0):

That would contradict Python's typing system.

In statically typed languages, not only does a data object in the memory has a type, but also the variable which references it, and the two types do not have to be identical (though they have to match). The class members accessible through the referencing variable depend usually on the variable's type, not the object's type.

Python is a dynamically typed language. Referencing variables do not have types, they are just labels pointing at the data objects. And since, in your case, A's name method returns an object of type B, this object obviously has access to all of B's class members. It does not know that it was originally created by A, it's just an ordinary B instance.